# Powershell: Cannot read and write a variable on Hyperv-V VM from host

Tags: powershell, virtual, hyper-v

Using this Powershell script I try to write and read a variable on VM from host.

```
$Username = 'administrator'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

#Added value to a variable on VM
Invoke-Command -VMName VM_Windows_2016 -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {$InstallPath="C:\Install\install-1.ps1"}
#Trying to read the variable on VM but with no result
Invoke-Command -VMName VM_Windows_2016 -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {Write-Host($InstallPath)}
```

As you see the result is empty. Can anyone help me to show how to write and read an variable on VM from host machine? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`Invoke-Command` to run a command remotely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1), any variables in the command are evaluated on the remote computer. So when you run the first `Invoke-Command` you are only defining the variable `$InstallPath` and terminating the remote PS session. When you are run the `Invoke-Command` second time it create entirely new PS session, hence `InstallPath` would be `null`. Instead of this you can define and read the [variable in a single Cmdlet like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1#example-5--invoke-a-command-with-a-script-block-stored-in-a-variable).

```
$remoteScriptblock = {
$InstallPath = "C:\Install\install-1.ps1"
Write-Host($InstallPath)
}
Invoke-Command -VMName VM_Windows_2016 -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock $remoteScriptblock
```

If you still want to run this in multiple Cmdlets you may consider [Run a command in a persistent connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1#example-3--run-a-command-in-a-persistent-connection)